# Reduce how finnicky YouTube oneboxing is in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox, youtube

I recently posted a link to this YouTube video in chat:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=ieFVN-PKLSA

Here's the link to the message in chat that didn't onebox:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9023882#9023882

It didn't onebox because of the ampersand before the `v` in the query string parameter (even though the link is completely valid).

I've also noticed that many YouTube links won't onebox if there are other query string parameters (which is *very* common in YouTube links, it's how they track a number of different things like referrals).

That said, could you just parse the query string and pull the `v` parameter for the video ID instead of whatever you're doing now?  All you need to do is call the [`ParseQueryString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) on the [`HttpUtility` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e55w41w.aspx) (you don't have to do it this way, but the point is, most of the work is done somewhere for you).

Also, if it's not too much trouble, would you recognize the shortened YouTube links that are formatted like this?

http://youtu.be/ieFVN-PKLSA

This is the link that's given out on the YouTube page when you want to share, and since I'm copying it to share it *here*, it would be nice if it was recognized.

Comment: I was gonna upvote this but I stopped reading at the first `&`

Comment: We like Regexes, that's why!

Comment: @Sklivvz Leave it to a former Skeptics mod to think that what's *built into the framework won't work*.  Granted, you might not want to attach a reference to `System.Web` but if it's there, use it (and this being an ASP.NET site, I can't imagine you *don't* have a reference *somewhere* in the app domain anyways).  Now I know you can fix it quickly.  Thanks, I'll expect it by EOD.  Toodles!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As these things go, it wasn't *that* easy... but it's done and will be out in the next deployment:

- Support for multiple parameters (e.g. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=ieFVN-PKLSA`)
- Support for shortened links (e.g. `http://youtu.be/ieFVN-PKLSA`)
- Support for fragments or parameters with start time (e.g. `http://youtu.be/ieFVN-PKLSA?t=3s` or `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieFVN-PKLSA&feature=youtu.be&t=15s` or also `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieFVN-PKLSA#t=15s`)

Not supported:

- non `.com` TLDs
- anything I've haven't thought of

Comment: Well, the "have it by EOD" wasn't serious (although the "Toodles!" was **deadly serious**), but that's awesome, thank you!  Will mark as accepted when I see it in chat.

Comment: @casperOne by the time you were expecting it, it was already done and I was writing this answer... the problem is usually not our speed, but the sheer amount of different things we need to do! Today was a relatively easy day when my normal developer duties got stuck and your request was at the top of the list :-)

Comment: Total fail: http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/9079664/history  You want that accept, you gotta work harder =)

Comment: @casperOne we didn't deploy yet - I'll do it on Monday when I'm fresh.

Comment: [So fresh, so clean](http://youtu.be/aU3Rk-Z9boM).

Comment: @casperOne done.